# Grunt amd: true for Gulp

Tags: backbone.js, gruntjs, gulp, requirejs, handlebars.js

I am doing an front-end application using :

- RequireJs
- BackboneJs
- Handlebars

To compile my template html to js for handlebars i used Grunt, and with those lines in the gruntfile.js

```
handlebars: {
  compile: {
      options: {                                                
          processName: function (fileName) {
              return path.basename(fileName, '.handlebars');
          },
     namespace: "Handlebars.templates",
          amd: true
    },
    files: {
        'src/templates/compiled/example.js':'src/templates/raw/example.handlebars'
    }
```

It work well, because in my example.js I have this first line :

```
define(['handlebars'], function(Handlebars) {
```

It seems like this line appear because of the `amd: true`, because if I remove, it does not work.

But the problem is, in Gulp how do I add this define on the compiled project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-handlebars/tree/master/examples/amd) explains that.

> ### Usage
>
> 1. Install development dependencies:
>
> ```
> npm install --save-dev gulp-handlebars gulp-define-module
> ```
>
> 2. Add the `require()` statements and `template` task to your gulpfile
>
> ```
> var gulp = require('gulp');
> var defineModule = require('gulp-define-module');
> var handlebars = require('gulp-handlebars');
>
> gulp.task('templates', function() {
>     // Load templates from the templates/ folder relative to where gulp was   executed
> gulp.src('source/templates/**/*.hbs')
>     // Compile each Handlebars template source file to a template function
>     .pipe(handlebars())
>     // Define templates as AMD modules
>     .pipe(defineModule('amd'))
>     // Write the output into the templates folder
>     .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/templates/'));
> });
> ```

Comment: That help a lot thank, but a problem persists, in the gulp file i have a '.pipe(declare({...}))' with a namespace and a noRedeclare, the console tell us 'SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list' for each files.

Comment: @NocideMugen check syntax there is typo.

Comment: Anyways that is a an other problem on what I 'm going to get over, thanks for the link.